# Poker cash game .. who has to Show cards when 2 players are All-In

Tags: rules, all-in, cash

Hi I have a very specific question .**cash game**

Villain goes all in, hero calls, cards are dealt villain shows winning hand,
Does villain have the right to ask to see heros cards.

PLEASE READ CAREFULLY,
**CAN VILLAIN WHO WENT ALL-IN REQUEST TO SEE** *CALLERS* **CARDS**.
(not asking about the other way round)

Comment: Are you talking about a situation 1) where the hand is not over yet because the flop/turn/river has not been dealt, or 2) where the hand is over, villain has shown the winning hand, and you were going to muck a losing hand without showing?

Comment: Yes exactly hand is over villain shows winning hand,, hero goes to muck his card .. villain requests to see hero cards  ...

Answer (score 2):

Of course they have the right to see the cards, they've paid for it. However it is often considered bad etiquette and slows the game down. If you've already won the hand people expect it to just move on and continue. So simply put yes villain absolutely has the right to request to see the cards, but do people like to show a loser, no of course they don't.

Personally I would never begrudge someone who wants to see the cards when they've paid to see them, it helps them build a range.

In cash games it's not strongly enforced, but technically the rules on an all-in situation are pretty clear, cards on their backs face-up. In a tournament as a former dealer, I wouldn't place another card or award a pot until all hands were on their backs. In cash it's very dependent on the game, if a player who paid to see the cards requests I would always expose the hand, even if the losing player didn't want to. However with that said, if the player never requested and the losing player didn't want to expose their hand I would just award the pot and move on. I've also dealt many places that had a show one show all rule, which often annoyed players who mucked and showed their cards to their neighbour only to have a dealer expose them to the entire table.

Comment: An apparent winner asking to see a hand also does so at his own risk: the dealer should show the hand without killing it, and it if wins, award the pot accordingly.

Comment: Oh absolutely agree @LeeDanielCrocker. Good addition to add!

Answer (score 0):

a short history of the showdown, I have been told that at one time everyone who made it to show down was required to table their hands face up, I do not know how long ago this custom died, but it evolved into anyone involved in the hand can ask to see a hand at showdown. and this has not changed,. the rule like this is handy and used for many reasons, one is to help curtail collision another good reason is to needle a player.it used to be when asked the dealer would ceremonially kill the hand by touching it to the muck. this is no longer done and the hand is considered live just as if the player tabled the hand, and the hand if it is best, can take the pot bringing some risk to not leaving well enough alone.